# Sound broken Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: pulseaudio

Sound works if booting from a live USB, but it is broken when the system is installed from the same live USB.

Answer (score 0):

Put `autospawn=no` into `.pulse/client.conf`.

This will cause Pulseaudio not to respawn.

Then simply kill it and start it again.

If that does not work, unload and load the modules before starting Pulseaudio again:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -i.bak -ne '/autospawn/ or print' ~/.pulse/client.conf
echo autospawn=no >> ~/.pulse/client.conf
pulseaudio -k
modules="
  snd_hda_intel
  snd_hda_codec_hdmi
  snd_hda_codec_analog
  snd_hda_codec_generic
  snd_hda_codec
  snd_hda_core
  snd_hwdep
  snd_pcm
  snd_seq_midi
  snd_seq_midi_event
  snd_rawmidi
  snd_seq
  snd_seq_device
  snd_timer
  snd
  soundcore
"
sudo parallel --retries=10 modprobe -r ::: $modules
lsmod|grep snd
sudo parallel -j1 modprobe ::: $modules
pulseaudio --log-level=3
```